# pivot table in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Here is the dataset from the table 
TABLE XYZ

```
    ID  Date        col1    col2    col3
     1  2012-09-21  100.00  0.00    0.00
     1  2012-09-21  0.00    10.00   20.00
     2  2012-09-21  0.00    20.00   0.00
     2  2012-09-21  100.00  0.00    20.00
     3  2012-09-21  10.00   25.00   5.00
```

I want Result like below:

```
 ID Date        COL
 1  2012-09-21  130.00
 2  2012-09-21  140.00
 3  2012-09-21  40.00
```

I tried below Query, but not getting a exact value from table.

```
        Select ID,
                 date,
                 sum(Col1+col2+col3) as COL
           From table xyz
         Group by ID,DATE
```

I got below result set

```
  ID    Date        COL
   1    2012-09-21  130.00
   2    2012-09-21  270.00
   3    2012-09-21  310.00
```

IS there any better way to get expected result set or to do a pivot table?

Thanks

Comment: Assuming there is no typo error since there is no comma after `date`, sql statement seems fine. what do you get when you execute the query?

Comment: I am not getting correct summation value  of Col1+Col2+Col3.

Comment: @David, you have already stated what you're not getting, what ARE you getting?

Comment: ID   Date        COL
 1  2012-09-21  130.00
 2  2012-09-21  140.00
 3  2012-09-21  40.00

Comment: Your query works fine. Are you sure that tou have zeros there?, not `NULL` values?. Try `SUM(ISNULL(Col1,0)+ISNULL(Col2,0)+ISNULL(Col3,0))`

Comment: @David That sure looks like the result that you want.  If it is wrong, then you should edit your question with more details about the issue.

Comment: There's no way you are getting those results with your query. You are performing (apparently unwillingly) a running total

Comment: I've tried your exact data set out, and your (corrected) query in my SQL Server 2008 instance, and I get the expected results.  Here is the query I tested with: http://pastebin.com/AgCYqXM2

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE and then use group by on the result.

WITH S AS ( SELECT ID,DATE,COL1+COL2+COL3 AS.    COLS FROM TABLE1);
    SELECT ID,DATE,SUM(COLS)
    FROM S
    GROUP BY ID,DATE